# Reduce border on link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, border

Brief - I need to make the spacing between the text and borders smaller.

What it looks like:

[image: what it looks like]

What it needs to look like:

[image: what it needs to look like]

**HTML -**

```
<div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS -**

```
a { font: 36px 'Bebas Neue', Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color: #d5a72b; border-top: 3px solid #d5a72b; border-bottom: 3px solid #d5a72b; border-spacing: 0; }
a.active { color: #d5a72b; border-top: 3px solid #d5a72b; border-bottom: 3px solid #d5a72b; }
```

Comment: So you need more than just the borders smaller? You need dashes and another li element.

Comment: well I am leaving contact out for now, and I know how to do the dashes, I just am asking for the borders in this case.

Comment: Oh, ok. Had me there. Looks like there's a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `line-height` property and with `padding`. In this case, you need to tweak `line-height`:

```
line-height: 10px;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Dj3/1/**

Comment: +1 Of course ;) slipped my mind. You can do cooler stuff with my answer (like not just put a border on top and bottom) but it is completely overkill if this is all you want.

Comment: so I went with this, less code. :P But here is whats happening
code - http://gyazo.com/d233dc4fa8a7f65027ed866476edb39b
outcome - http://gyazo.com/e86c7ea8b6ca49d37919a81ab2844b61
It goes off page....

Comment: It looks like your line height is something like 5px or something. It needs to be the distance between the top and bottom borders, more like 30px.

Comment: In the end I got it to work how I wanted it to, thanks guys for all the help, man do I love this site. Atleast I know I will never be a pro developer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reduce the space between text and borders. Here is a solution using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. To adjust the spacing change the `top` and `bottom` values.

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Dj3/)

```
a { 
    font: 36px 'Bebas Neue', Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    color: red; 
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}

a:before,
a:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:4px;
    background-color:#000;
}

a:before {
    top:2px;
}

a:after {
    bottom:2px;
}
```

Also a handy trick, you can change 'Home' to 'HOME' through CSS using the following rule:

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```

Comment: No I have that, but how do I get the margins set now, I tried to do margin: 10px 0; to center it top and bottom, but it did absolutely nothing. `a { 
    font: 36px 'Bebas Neue', Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}`

Comment: You would need to use padding to change the 'margin'. Check if line-height works out as that's a much simpler solution for the requirements.